# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CategoryID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have found a lot of similar threads on this problem. But whatever I do, it never works for me.

The ONLY thing I want to achieve right now, is to fill a dropdown list with database values in a partial view, that's within a partial view. That is all, and this is driving me absolutely nuts. A user should be able to chose a category name in the dropdown list.

Here's my Controller Class:

```
public class AttributeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<ClassLibrary.Entities.Attribute> _aRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<Category> _cRepository;

    public AttributeController() : this(new Repository<ClassLibrary.Entities.Attribute>(), new Repository<Category>())
    { 
    }

    public AttributeController(IRepository<ClassLibrary.Entities.Attribute> repo, IRepository<Category> repository)
    {
        _aRepository = repo;
        _cRepository = repository;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Attribute/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var attributes = _aRepository.GetAll();
        var attributeViewModels = new List<AttributeViewModel>();

        foreach (ClassLibrary.Entities.Attribute attribute in attributes)
        {
            var viewModel = new AttributeViewModel();
            viewModel.Id = attribute.Id;
            viewModel.AttributeName = attribute.Name;
            attributeViewModels.Add(viewModel);
        }



        return View(attributeViewModels);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Attribute/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Attribute/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["CategoryID"] = new SelectList(_cRepository.GetAll().ToList(), "Category_id", "Category");
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = _cRepository.GetAll().Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                                                Text = c.Name
                                            });

        ViewData["CategoryID"] = items;

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Attribute/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And here's the index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<GUI.Models.AttributeViewModel>

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Attributes";
 }

<div>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Attribute/Create.cshtml", new GUI.Models.AttributeViewModel())
</div>

<h2>All existing Attributes</h2>



<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AttributeName)
    </th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

@if(Model != null)
{ 
  foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AttributeName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
}

</table>
```

Here's the partial View Within the index view:

```
@model GUI.Models.AttributeViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Create an attribute for this Category</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Attribute/CategoryPartial.cshtml", new  GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel())
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttributeName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AttributeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AttributeName)
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    </div>
  }


  @section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  }
```

And finally CategoryPartialView within the partial view that will contain the DropDown List where the user should be able to select a category Name.

```
@model GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel
@using GUI.Controllers

@using System.Collections.Generic
@{
//var categories = (IEnumerable<GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel>)ViewData["categories"];
 }


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()



    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CategoryID"])
        </div>
    </div>     


   }
```

The exception ALWAYS occurs when I'm debugging the application and it points to the @Html.DropDownList part. Claiming that "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'CategoryID".

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CategoryID"]
```

I'm sorry for posting so many code blocks. But I would really like to solve this.I've beaten my head against the wall for hours with frustration, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `ViewData` dictionary does not get "inherited". You need to reset it in each (partial) view, until you reach your target. You might need to change its name during these resets... Btw, I'm not seeing where and how you call your `CategoryPartialView`.

Comment: I edited my post and now I call the CategoryPartialView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Attribute/CategoryPartial.cshtml", new  GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel())` you are directly instantiating the partial view. The controller does not get called and is not responsible for generating the HTML markup string. Additionally, you are passing an empty view model (`new  GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel()`). Since the controller does not get called, it does not get the data for the drop down list and, obviously, does not save it in your `ViewData`.

Use the `@Html.Action` helper instead:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Action("Create", "Attribute")
<div class="form-group">
```

Change the `Create` action like this:

```
//
// GET: /Attribute/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["CategoryID"] = new SelectList(_cRepository.GetAll().ToList(), "Category_id", "Category");
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = _cRepository.GetAll().Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                                            Text = c.Name
                                        });

    ViewData["CategoryID"] = items;

    return PartialView("CategoryPartial", new GUI.Models.CategoryViewModel());
}
```

Note: I don't know your entire structure, but I might be best to use this approach and to return a `Lis<SelectListItem>` model.

Comment: That's an eyopener. I think I'm getting closer.

But in the CategoryPartial View I got the: "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CategoryID".

And for some reason when I'm running the application and setting the breakpoint in the Create action in the Controller, it doesn't step in and find it.

Comment: '@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID")' is what I have in the View right now, or do I need to change that as well?

Comment: You need to use your original version, by casting to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`: ` @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CategoryID"])`. Additionally, set a break point inside your partial view and inspect the `ViewData` to check if there is an object with the "CategoryID" key inside.

Comment: Now I entered the breakpoint in the partial view.

It looks like this in the Locals debugging window in Visual Studio: this => base => ViewData => base => Keys => [0] "categories"

It seems like the key value in the viewdata dictionary is named: "categories"

Comment: @Assassin87, that's weird. Does it contain the `List<SelectListItem>` data that you "pass" in controller?

Comment: Seems like I mixed up with my views. Now I managed to call the Controller Create action with a breakpoint. Hopefully things will be more clear now.

Comment: It worked! It finally worked! You've been incredibly helpful Andrei. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Assassin87, don't mention it. Keep up with the practice.

Answer (score 0):

when calling:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Attribute/Create.cshtml", new GUI.Models.AttributeViewModel())
```

you call the view directly with out passing throw the controller so the model you have there is an empty model!

try pass throw the controller to create you'r model and send it back as a view:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("YOUR CONTROLLER",model);
```